# LaTeX, $\LaTeX$ or $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$?

Tags: discussion

What is the preferred way to write the name "LaTeX" on this site? A few questions use `$\LaTeX$` in order to get the LaTeX name; however that looks wrong to me because it makes the letters italics, which isn't the case with the "proper" typeset name. You can get that name with `$\mathrm{\LaTeX}$` which looks quite perfect (at least where LaTeX is enabled) but is a lot to type. And of course there exists the standard textual form `LaTeX` matching the name of the macro, and quite usual where you are restricted to pure text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use whichever way you like best.  Even when writing `$\LaTeX$`, post titles are searchable, so this has no disadvantage.  I wouldn't bother too much trying to get it to look excellent: it doesn't look perfect when MathML rendering is used anyway (and I need to use MathML rendering, otherwise long posts are painfully slow to edit when they have formulae)